# Call function only once across multiple instances of a class

Tags: python, selenium, oop, web-scraping

I am very new to Python and Web Scraping so if you could improve my code and reply with your improved version it would be much appreciated.

I am scraping job postings from Indeed (web scraping - selenium) and exporting them to a spreadsheet.
There are 2 jobs I want to search for: 1. Software Engineer, 2. Software Developer

I don't want to login on Indeed to search 'Software Engineer Jobs' and then login again to search 'Software Developer Jobs'. I want to call this `login_indeed()` function once and then call all other function like `search_jobs()` every time a new instance of a class is made

```
class IndeedJobScraper:
    def __init__(position, location):
        self.position = position
        self.location = location
    
    def login_indeed(self): # I WANT TO CALL THIS ONCE
        # input username and password
    
    def search_jobs(self)  
        # input job title and location into search boxes
    
    def retrieve_jobs(self)
        self.login()
        self.search_jobs()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj1 = IndeedJobScraper('Software Engineer', 'Ireland')
    obj1.retrieve_jobs()

    obj2 = IndeedJobScraper('Software Developer', 'Ireland')
    obj2.retrieve_jobs()
```

Currently:
When `obj1` created:
- Login to Indeed
- Search for Software Engineer Jobs

```
When `obj1` created:
- Login to Indeed
- Search for Software Engineer Jobs
```

I Want:
When `obj1` created:
- Login to Indeed
- Search for Software Engineer Jobs

```
When `obj2` created:
- ̶L̶o̶g̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶I̶n̶d̶e̶e̶d̶
- Search for Software Engineer Jobs
```

So... I 'login_indeed' (1x) and 'search_jobs' (2x)

Thanks

Comment: An instance of `IndeedJobScrape` should not open its own connection; it should receive one as an argument to `__init__`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Hi, I tried to do just that but I am unsure how. If possible could you send the code that helps me do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make authorization once in constructor, create object once and then call your search methods whenever you need. For example I would write like that:

```
class IndeedJobScraper:
    def __init__(self):
        # input username and password
        pass
    
    def search_jobs(self, position, location)  
        # input job title and location into search boxes
    
    def retrieve_jobs(self, position, location)
        self.search_jobs(position, location)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj1 = IndeedJobScraper()
    obj1.retrieve_jobs('Software Engineer', 'Ireland')
    obj1.retrieve_jobs('Software Developer', 'Ireland')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and IT WORKS!!!!. Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @Carcigenicate, what you'll want to do is have an attribute in your `__init__` that initializes as `self.logged_in = False`. Then I would have a condition in `login_indeed()` function to check if `logged_in == True`, if `logged_in` is False then log in and update the attribute. Otherwise, then if it's already logged in you continue with the rest of the function.